# Regular expression: match something but exclude a case

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
"1042 - 23059": [1042.00, 23059,00, 129,69, 243790,98]
```

How do I match only the commas that are found between two numbers?

Comment: the question is unreadable - update it

Comment: is it more clear?

Comment: What language are you using (please edit the tags of your question)? Let's hope it's not JavaScript (because of its lack of support for lookbehind assertions)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [negative look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), your regex would look like this: `,(?! )`

**Update**: The question was changed in the meantime.
To match a comma only when it's surrounded by numbers, one doesn't even need look-ahead/look-behind, just use: `\d(,)\d`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that the comma is between two numbers.

For example:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O6dv8L/2)